# DrawerLayout don't work properly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="xxxxxxx.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MapLocationActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Title fill all my screen (blue screen with app tile on top). If I use: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout instead of DrawerLayout all look great. But I need a DrawerLayout because want to show a navigation layout.

What I do wrong? Thx for support!

Comment: Your `DrawerLayout` should have only two direct children; the main content, and the drawer. Put everything that's not the drawer into another `ViewGroup` - e.g., a `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, etc. - then put the drawer after that.

Comment: you have right, thank you!